# change font/text color in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want to change the font color of my navigation bar. I tried color:xxx; font color:xxx; everywhere it is not working. I am thinking something is canceling it out but I can not figure out what. I what to change it from red to white. Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
 <ul id="drop-nav">
      <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="parks.html">Parks</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="magickingdom.html">Magic Kingdom</a></li>
          <li><a href="epcot.html">EPCOT</a></li>
          <li><a href="hollywoodstudios.html">Hollywood Studios</a></li>
      <li><a href="animalkingdom.html">Animal Kingdom</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="kids.html">Kids</a></li>
      <li><a href="discounts.html">Discounts</a></li>
      <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="tips.html">Tips</a></li>

  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ul {  /*remove bullets & margins & padding from list*/
    list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 2px; 
  }

  ul li {  /*navigation bar*/
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border:2px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 85px;
`  `margin-bottom: 30px;
`  `background-color: black;
      }
  li ul {display: none; }
  ul li a {display: block; background: red; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; text-decoration:none;
            white-space: nowrap; color: white; border: 2px solid black;
           }
   ul li a:hover {background: red; }
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute; left: auto; right: 0; margin-right: -60px; }
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: red;text-decoration: none; color: black; text-align: center;  }
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000; color: red;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px; }
```

Comment: Do you close your style tag anywhere?

Comment: Also, can you be more clear as to what you want to turn white. The text in the main menu is white. When hovered over it turns black. The text underneath the Parks menu is black but turns red when hovered over.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tacequzebo/edit?html,css,js,output working `ul li a` is overriding the class `ul li`

Comment: This code example works fine in chrome and IE,  The font is White and when hovered it is black.

Answer (score 0):

change your css to this.I only concerned about your text color and background color,

```
  ul li{
    background-color: red;
  }

  ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }

  ul li:hover{
    background: white;
  }

  ul li a:hover{
    color: red;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try !important in css

color : XXX !important